# Deploy a Tensorflow model avoiding Tensorflow Serving

Tags: deployment, tensorflow

Is there any good way to save and then run a tensorflow model without utilizing Tensorflow Serving. My model is pretty simple and requires only sequential serving for inference on my PC. So I think there should be a better way to avoid using too rich and complicated Tensorflow Serving system.

What I am doing now is saving all weights and the session after training; and, for inference, I define the graph again, restore session and load weights. Is that a reasonable way to do?

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) . In one of the routes you define you query your model. Would this help you?